# Arch Linux Wi-Fi no longer working

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, arch-linux

I installed Arch Linux a few weeks ago and ever since I booted it up yesterday I've been having an issue where my Wi-Fi doesn't want to work, despite it working without issue until this point.

I looked into a few other threads and upon doing running (`ip link`) i got the result:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

Another thread I saw had the same result and a response mentioned to run (`ls /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf`) and the directories listed were (`all`, `default`, `lo`).

The thread mentioned that there should a `wlan0` directory and continued assuming there was however this is not the case for me.

How do I restore Wi-Fi access on my system?

Upon being asked to run lspci -k My network adapter is:

```
0000:01:00.0 Network Controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
DeviceName: Realtek Wireless LAN + BT
SubSystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 87fd
```

Having run the commands `pacman -Q linux` and  `uname -r` I can see that they are different, as `pacman -Q linux` returns `linux 6.1.1.arch1-1` and `uname -r` returns `6.0.12-arch1-1`

`lsblk` lists:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN  RM  SIZE  RO  TYPE  MOUNTPOINTZ
nvme0n1  259:0  0  238.5G  0  disk
|-nvme0n1p1  259:1  0  256M  0 part
'-nvme0n1p2  259:2  0  238.2G  0  part  /
```

Following the given answer, I ran `mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /boot` and I got the error:

```
mount: /boot: unknown filestsytem type 'vfat'
dmesg(1) may have more information after mount system call.
```

Comment: Are you absolutely certain it used to work? Did you change anything (installed updates, different hardware, …)? Do you know the make and model of your Wi-Fi adapter? Did it originally work out-of-the-box or did you have to install drivers manually?

Comment: You may start from checking/sharing `dmesg`/`journalctl -k`. `lspci -k` may also help if it's an internal WiFi adapter.

Comment: It absolutely did used to work. I haven't had any hardware changes (I'm running from an old laptop) According to lspci -k my network controller is a Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the full output instead (at least the full output of this device).

Comment: You may also check `pacman -Q linux` and `uname -r` to see if they give the same version btw.

Comment: I ran those commands and added the ouput to the question. Unsure what to do next

Comment: The problem is that you failed to upgrade the kernel package properly. Reasons could be the `/boot` partition (if any) was not mounted when you `pacman -Syu`, or when you installed your bootloader. To find out the exact cause you will need to provide more information like your partition layout and `findmnt /boot` output, etc.

Comment: findmnt /boot returns nothing.

Comment: So did you plan to have a separate `/boot` partition (which might be also the EFI partition btw) when you installed?

Comment: Yes my laptop required EFI so I did make a partition for it, though lsblk doesn't mention which parition is /boot. I added lsblk output to the original post

Answer (score 1):

The reason your wireless NIC is "gone" is because your bootloader is loading an older kernel image, while there is (only) the newer driver for the NIC in the root filesystem, partly because of the rolling update nature of Arch (with the other part of the reason being your PEBKAC, that you didn't have the `/boot` partition mounted when you "designed" to use one when you installed the OS / bootloader.)

EDIT: I forgot that you actually have to downgrade the kernel first. You might check whether the older version package (the exact one as per `uname -r`) is in `/var/cache/pacman/pkg/`. If not, download it [here](https://archive.archlinux.org/packages/l/linux/). Then run:

```
pacman -U path/to/older/package
```

<strike>Then reboot and continue with the steps below.</strike> Actually you should be able to continue without rebooting at this point.

Try to `mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /boot` and see if there is `vmlinuz-linux` under `/boot` (with e.g. `ls`) *after* the `mount` command.

*If so*, `pacman -S linux` to reinstall the kernel package and reboot to see if you get your WiFi back.

*If so*, remove all files under `/boot`. (`findmnt /boot` should give you no output again after the reboot; and there should only be `vmlinuz-linux` and one or two `initramfs` files. If there are other files skip this step and maybe let me know what else are there.)

Finally add an entry for `/boot` to `/etc/fstab`. For example:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1 /boot vfat defaults 0 2
```

(Better replace `/dev/nvme0n1p1` with `UUID=...`, where `...` should be the UUID of the filesystem on `/dev/nvme0n1`, which you can obtain with `lsblk -f`.)

Then you can run:

```
mount /boot
```

If it runs fine you may also reboot as a paranoia check to see if `/boot` is mounted automatically upon boot now.

Comment: I tried to I run `mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /boot` and i got the error in my update

Comment: See the edited answer. My bad.

Comment: Sorry for the Delayed response, but yeah that worked. Thanks a million